# Varnish on nGinx and PhpMyAdmin Redirect Issue

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, varnish

I have nginx setup with Varnish in front of it, and while it works perfect (including wp-admin :)), I am finding that `phpmyadmin` when attached to a vhost does nothing but redirect on the home login form.

I've tried everything on Google, including adding the absolute url to pma's config... and it still happens

Is there another way I can "force" pma to be served only by nginx instead of the varnish front-end?

Comment: Could you describe how do you pass the PhpMyAdmin requests from Varnish to Nginx? Could you also post your vcl and nginx config?

Comment: Sorry, just seeing this.   Should I post them to pastebin or something?   Just seems like they would take up alot or real-estate in the question...

To answer, Varnish is set to run on port 80, Nginx on Port 8080, and configured to pass like that.   All other sites on the server work just fine... it's just pma pukes with the exact same config as the rest...

Comment: You could post only your Varnish vcl and you nginx vhost here or pastebin. The config is just to try to figure out what is happening and to help you with the new setup giving examples based on your configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.

In the **vcl_recv {}** section in your varnish config you can instruct varnish to skip caching for your phpMyAdmin based on a folder location (if phpMyAdmin is installed in a folder and it's accesible like `http://domain.com/phpmyadmin`

```
sub vcl_recv {

if (req.url ~ "^/phpmyadmin") {
  return (pass);
}
```

Or if it's installed on a subdomain or whatever then:

```
sub vcl_recv {
# disable caching for applemov.com
if (req.http.host ~ "(phpmyadmin.domain.com)") {
        return(pass);
}
```